# Convert Premium To Standard

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

We have a VM using premium managed drives that is also replicated to another azure data center using azure site recovery. I am aware of how to convert the premium drives to standard by deallocating the vm and changing the drive type. However I suspect I will need to stop and remove the disaster recovery replication and reinitializing vm replication resulting in the loss of all previous recovery points.

Does anyone know for sure and what the process to convert the disks given VM replication would be.

Thx.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems like something you should be mailing the Azure team over as opposed to us on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The Azure Team directs support to the StackOverflow community and there are dozens if not hundreds of Azure questions already answered here. I considered this might be better posted on serverfault but after finding several answered questions on the same topic on StackOverflow without VM replication I started here. I will gladly repost on serverfault necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reach out to the right Azure Support Team.  The Azure Site Recovery support team should be able to give you the correct information, they handle disaster recovery replication scenario.

**You want to make sure you are getting vetted information on issues like this.**